# Python multi-threaded unittesting

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, testing, thread-safety

I use a multi-threaded design (had no choice), but most of my code resides in a single thread where all events in it are managed via a [queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html). In this fashion most of my code behaves as if it is single threaded, and I don't have to worry about locks, semaphores and what not.

Alas I've come to the point where I need to unittest my code (please don't lash for not TDDing in the first place), and I'm at a loss - how do you test something in another thread?

For instance, say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=0
        # register event to self.on_event

    def on_some_event(self, b):
        self.a += b

    def get(self):
        return self.a
```

and I want to test:

```
import unittest
from queued_thread import ThreadedQueueHandler

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create the queued thread and assign the queue to self.queue

    def test_MyClass(self):
        mc = MyClass()
        self.queue.put({'event_name':'some_event', 'val':1})
        self.queue.put({'event_name':'some_event', 'val':2})
        self.queue.put({'event_name':'some_event', 'val':3})
        self.assertEqual(mc.get(),6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

`MyClass.get()` works fine for anything inside the queued thread, but it will be called asynchronously in the main thread by the test, thus the result may not be correct!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your design assumes everything must go through the queue, then don't fight it - make everything go through it!

Add an `on_call` event to your queued event handler, and register to it the following function:

```
def on_call(self, callback):
    callback()
```

then modify your test to:

```
def test_MyClass(self):
    def threaded_test():
        self.assertEqual(mc.get(),6)

    mc = MyClass()
    self.queue.put(1)
    self.queue.put(2)
    self.queue.put(3)
    self.queue.put({'event_name':'call','val':threaded_test})
```

Comment: This might be the most practical (i.e. not just a dupe target) self-answered question I've seen on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [test_threading.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3dc602b1f4a2/Lib/test/test_threading.py) in the stdlib tests which does something similar to what you are trying to do. The basic idea is to protect a thread execution with mutex and semaphore so that the execution is complete before the test condition is asserted.

Comment: Any chance you know of a tutorial\doc for this?

Comment: The code I linked itself is easier to follow and you may take some help with threading documentation at python.org docs.